# Unsupported get request in get Facebook event

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an issue with Facebook Graph end get data event.

If i do ( from here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) :

```
GET /[event-id]/
```

The output is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "D5OGA3wEZDB"
  }
}
```

I have the access token with `user_events` permission.

But if i click on "Partecipate" button on the event page, then after the call is successful.

So I can not get info about an event if I don't set the `rsvp_status`?

Answer (score 6):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

> Testing of our more robust process starts today and the new process should resume in a few weeks, but **apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access today**.

Right now, it is just not possible and you can only wait.

Answer (score -1):

I already have the same problem, and I think this is not the reason because on this page : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event we can see

> An access token of an Admin of the Event if required

We must be admin of event for get event details :(