# Why Facebook Graph API doesn't list all public events for a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There're lots of events for this venue:
https://www.facebook.com/pg/ClubRoxyPrague/events/
However when requesting with Graph API we only get a few. Here's link to Graph API explorer:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=ClubRoxyPrague%2Fevents&version=v2.12
Until recently this worked well for us. Maybe it's data access restrictions Facebook announced few days ago: https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access/

Why the API returns only some events? Is there any way to fetch **all public events** hosted by a certain page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the breaking data access changes you mentioned, it already wasn't possible to access events directly (also see: [Unsupported get request in get Facebook event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749909/unsupported-get-request-in-get-facebook-event)).

It seems like your specific issue is a logical consequence of that decision (although the `/{page-id}/events` was still available up to today, I personally already found it pretty strange that events were still accessible indirectly).

Comment: Checking it now the events disappeared even from the page API (`/page-id/events`) Well what's some bad news. I guess we can only hope they'll provide at least some access in upcoming weeks.

Comment: Any news on this? Do we know if the "Page Public Content Access" permission grants you access to the events of is there any other way to get them?